# Getting compile time error Inference variable T has incompatible bounds

Tags: java, java-stream, guava, option-type

```
class CollectorUtils {
    private CollectorUtils() {
    }

    public static <T> Collector<T, ?, T> onlyElement() {
        return Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Iterables::getOnlyElement);
    }

    public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Optional<T>> optionalElement() {
        return Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), (list) -> {
            return Optional.ofNullable(Iterables.getOnlyElement(list, (Object)null));
        });
    }

    public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
        return Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new);
    }
}
```

I am getting inference variable T has incompatible bounds.

java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: T
lower bounds: T,java.lang.Object,T

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? What is `Iterables.getOnlyElement`?

Comment: When asking about compiler errors, please include the line number, or otherwise indicate which node is being marked by the compiler. In addition, consider pasting any code that is involved, such as Iterables.getOnlyElement.

Comment: If you're using Guava at all to get `Iterables.getOnlyElement`, why not use [these collectors from that library](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE:** In this answer I'm only considering the compilation error. I'm not discussing whether the code of the question is the best possible one or not.

---

I assume `Iterables.getOnlyElement` is from Guava.

The problem is with this line:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(Iterables.getOnlyElement(list, (Object) null));
```

Instead, cast `null` to `T`, so that the compiler can safely infer all types:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(Iterables.getOnlyElement(list, (T) null));
```

Also, you can simplify your code:

```
return Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
    list -> Optional.ofNullable(Iterables.getOnlyElement(list, (T) null)));
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that the result of the approach is inconsistent. It will treat a stream with a single `null` element like an empty stream, returning an empty optional, but throw an exception for a stream containing two `null` elements. In contrast, the simpler and more efficient `return Collectors.reducing((a,b) -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException("multiple elements"); });` will behave exactly like the [`MoreCollectors.toOptional()`](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.html#toOptional--) that the OP seems be be trying to mimic.

Comment: @Holger Not to mention that OP is collecting the whole stream to a list, just to return its first element (if present). In my answer, I only considered the compilation error and syntax

Comment: Well, the `getOnlyElement` method is supposed to throw when there’s more than one element, so “collecting the whole stream” is only expensive in the erroneous case. Still, the implementation of `toList()` typically produces an `ArrayList` with the default capacity of ten, which is unnecessary for getting zero or one element, so there is a performance penalty with that approach, which is why I wrote “simpler and more efficient”.